# I have set services.sync.prefs.sync.dom.disable_window_move_resize;false but resizeTo() still doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I am using Aurora 14.0a2 as my default browser (its the early release of firefox)
I have went into my about:config and have changed the value of services.sync.prefs.sync.dom.disable_window_move_resize; to false 
Yet when I run my website the resizeTo(); function still doesn't work

here is my code:
[jsfiddle_link](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlerOnDaRoof/ZVmpn/2/)

```
function onload(){
    window.resizeTo(600,800);
}
```

I also tried it in other browsers:
Chrome (no surprise it didn't work since chrome never supports it)
opera 
IE 8
Safari

None of which worked

I also tried making a link from a different website linking my website then clicking on it but it did not do the trick

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the resize functionality of javascript would only work when you open it on popup windows and not when your openning it on a main browser window try checking on this link http://www.javascripter.net/faq/windowresizeto.htm it has the sample that I think would help you.

Comment: yea i just thought of that as well... its a piety that this functionality is so heavily limited it is rarely useful but for drag and drop upload it would be really nice to have it. Now that i made firefox open it in a new window it works... thanks for helping